# reshape an uneven data frame in pandas from jagged wide to tall

Tags: pandas, reshape

I have 5k rows, each row has upto 10 associated values, such as:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','b','c'],'col2':['a1,a2,a3','b1','c1,c2']})

    col1    col2
0   a   a1,a2,a3
1   b   b1
2   c   c1,c2
```

I want to make a unique mapping like:

```
pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','a','a','b','c','c'],'col2':['a1','a2','a3','b1','c1','c2']})
col1    col2
0   a   a1
1   a   a2
2   a   a3
3   b   b1
4   c   c1
5   c   c2
```

I tried `df.explode('col2')`, but it does not work

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to convert to **list**,then you could use[`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df['col2']=df['col2'].str.split(',')
df=df.explode('col2')
print(df)
```

---

```
  col1 col2
0    a   a1
0    a   a2
0    a   a3
1    b   b1
2    c   c1
2    c   c2
```

**pandas <0.25:**

```
df['col2']=df['col2'].str.split(',')
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':df.col1.repeat(df.col2.str.len()),'B':np.concatenate(df.col2.values)})
print(df)

  col1   B
0    a  a1
0    a  a2
0    a  a3
1    b  b1
2    c  c1
2    c  c2
```

Comment: I was thinking for ages on how to convert to a list. Thanks!!